# Why does Java force generic types to be cast?

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

I do not understand why the compiler can not see that a cast is safe when the parameterized type is defined as extending a base class. Here are examples of casts that seem to me like they should be unnecessary. Further, when I do include the cast, my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) warns that the cast is unchecked, as if to suggest that I am doing something wrong. Is there an idiom that avoids these casts and warnings? Why are the casts needed at all, given that the declaration states that the type extends the base class?

```
class Shape {}

class Polygon extends Shape {}

public class Foo<T extends Shape>
{
  Set<Polygon> polygons;
  // Why must this be cast?
  Set<T> shapes = (Set<T>) new HashSet<Polygon>(); 

  T getFirst()
  {
    // Why must this be cast?
    return (T) polygons.iterator().next();
  }

  Iterable<T> getShapes()
  {
    // Why must this be cast?
    return (Iterable<T>) polygons;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you've instantiated your class like this:

```
Foo<Circle> circleFoo = new Foo<Circle>( );
```

Then, `Set<Circle>` cannot be safely assigned `HashSet<Polygon>`

In `getFirst`: You cannot safely cast `Polygon` to `Circle`

And in `getShapes`: you cannot safely cast `Iterable<Polygon>` to `Iterable<Circle>`.

Comment: I understood this at one point. Thanks for the succinct refresher.

Answer (score 5):

T extends Shape, Polygon extends Shape.
So there is no reason that T extends Polygon

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in reading [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) about Java generics.

Basically,

```
  Box<Integer> and Box<Double> are not subtypes of Box<Number>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<T> shapes = (Set<T>) new HashSet<Polygon>();
```

A cast is needed as `T` here can  be anything that extends `Shape` and you are trying to fit only Polygons. `Circle` is a `shape` but its not `Polygon`. The best practice is to treat parameterized generics as a unique class.

If java allowed the above without the cast, it would then be opening a door for adding any `T` to the `set`. Imagine you assigned your `Polygon` set to a `Set<T>` and then added `Circle` objects to it. That's inviting lots of runtime problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Why must this be cast?
Set<T> shapes = (Set<T>) new HashSet<Polygon>();
```

This is the least of your problems. The conversion is actually *logically incorrect*. `Set<A>` is not a subtype of `Set<B>` if A and B are different, even if A is a subtype of B. If we had reifiable generics this cast would fail.

Comment: I see that now. This code is only correct in the case where class `Foo` is instantiated with type parameters `Shape` or `Polygon`. FWIW, I am working with an api where an argument of type `Class<T>` is passed in and within the method you call `clazz.isAssignableFrom(Polygon.class)` to determine which casts are safe.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `Set<T>` is not a base class of `HashSet<Polygon>`.

In the second example, the type of `polygons.iterator().next()` is `Polygon`, which is not the same as `T`.